# any way to make my webbrick server run faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm running webbrick server on my computer, it is a very simple image uploading website.
currently I have the image uploaded into the database and saved as binary. but it literally like a minute to upload an 1MB file. Is there a way to make it go faster? Perhaps a different storing method like BLOBS?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using different webserver. [unicorn](http://rubygems.org/gems/unicorn) would be dead simple to start with.